# How could you allow users to upload a video in within their profile and display it on a wordpress site?

Tags: uploads, media

*Does anyone know of a plugin that already allows a user(subscriber non-admin) to upload a video/video link?*

very **similar to** this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380037/wordpress-media-as-a-custom-post-type

**Dated 2010**.. which is why I started a new post.. alot has changed..

I have set up a login so far with **WP User Manager** and need to **allow a user to upload a video link or video** so that the video is displayed on their profile.

**Working on** using Advanced Custom Fields PRO to make it frontend in hopes this might work.

documentation:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Possibly WooCommerce Events Could do this all in one plugin.. I am checking now!

Answer (score 0):

Try WP-Recall plugin and addon [Video Gallery](https://codeseller.ru/products/dopolnenie-video-gallery-gibkaya-polzovatelskaya-videogalereya-dlya-wp-recall/)

Works through a frontend